# H1b extension beyond 6 years with AC21

Tags: usa, visa

Is the H1b extension beyond six years with approved I-140 only possible because of AC21 act?

My visa is approved beyond 6 years using a approved I-140, and, I just wanted to find out if this extension was based on AC21 or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is based on your approved immigration petition. This is not part of AC21, it has been there before. Here's the [full list](http://www.usavisanow.com/h-1b-visa/h1b-visa-resources/h-1b-renewal-extension/) of options.